# How ref a postgres function param using psql variable as prefix

Tags: postgresql, psql

When specifying a new postgres object in a schema, I like to use a psql variable to name it.  I'll use the variable in all the places I would otherwise "copy/paste" it's value.

Here is an example:

```sql
\set obj_name 'try_validate_subscriber'

create or replace function api.:obj_name(  -- works
    IN subscription_token text
) returns void as $$
    update core.users
    set
        subscription_status = 'confirmed'::core.subscription_status,
        validated_email = email
    from core.subscription_tokens
    where id = user_id
    and subscription_token = :obj_name.subscription_token;  -- syntax error
$$ language sql security definer
set search_path = api, pg_temp;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
comment on function api.:obj_name is  -- works
    'Upgrade the status of a subscriber';
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Permissions
grant execute on function api.:obj_name to webuser;  -- works
```

The syntax error:

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 10:     and subscription_token = :obj_name.subscription_token;
                                      ^
```

I can use the variable to ref a function name, even when prefixed by the schema name.

I cannot figure out the syntax to have it be interpreted as a ref to a function in order to get a reference to its parameters.  I get that there is a difference between the two use-cases (`function <obj_name>`, vs `<obj_name>`), I just can't put my finger on whether it's even possible, if so, how to get the syntax right.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.
Because $$..........$$ is a text string. The whole $$...$$ body text part is like text inside the text.
There is not way to escape it. Because this part is already defined as string. it won't escape it and do evaluation.

The best I can come up with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HELLO (a int)
    RETURNS void
    AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%', hello.a;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

\set a 11000
SELECT
    hello (:a);
```